# Show image file by id in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table named files, this saves the name of the images related to the properties table.

I am trying to make these images appear as in the following relation.

This is part of the properties table.

[image]

This is the table files and their relationship to the properties table.

[image]

What parameter can I pass in the show method of my controller (PropertyController)?

Currently I have the following:

```
public function show($id)
{
 $properties = Property::find($id);

 $files = File::all();

 return View::make('properties.show', ['properties' => $properties, 'files' => $files]);
}
```

But it returns to the view all the images stored in the files table.

```
@foreach($files as $file) 

    <div class="col-md-6 thumb">
        <a class="thumbnail">
            <img id="myImg" src="{{ URL::asset('uploads/products/' . $file->name) }}" alt="{{ $file->name }}" width="300" height="200">
        </a>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

Which method would be correct so that the images related to the records can be displayed by id in the properties table?

Comment: Please check my answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using `hasMany()` relationship between `Property` and `File` models. If not, create the relation in the `Property` model:

```
public function files()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\File');
}
```

To load the property with all it's images use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
public function show($id)
{
    $property = Property::with('files')->find($id);
    return view('properties.show', compact('property'));
}
```

To display images:

```
@foreach($property->files as $file) 
    // Here use the same code you used before.
@endforeach
```

Alternatively, you can load data separately:

```
public function show($id)
{
    $property = Property::find($id);
    $files = File::where('property_id', $property->id)->get();
    return view('properties.show', compact('property', 'files'));
}
```

Comment: I applied the changes as recommended, but it returns the following error in the view: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\crminmobiliario\resources\views\layouts\gallery.blade.php)

Comment: @EdwardPalen are you talking about the first method or the second one? Check if you're using correct variable names. If everything's fine and you're talking about eager loading method, please post result of `{{ dd($property) }}`

Comment: Ok, I have corrected the variable but it is generating the following error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::files()

Comment: That error is with the first method, with the second generating an error with the variable in the view:

Comment: @EdwardPalen this means you didn't create `files` relation. You can use the second method without creating relation or you can define the relationship which you can find in an updated answer.

Comment: @EdwardPalen rename the relationship to `files()`

Comment: Yes, I checked the method and corrected my error, thank you very much and it is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In your Property model, define your hasMany method like this:

```
public function files()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\File');
}
```

Your show method in your controller will be like this:

```
public function show($id)
{
 $property = Property::find($id);

 $files = $property->files;

 return View::make('properties.show', ['property' => $property, 'files' => $files]);
}
```

Comment: Yes, I checked the method and corrected my error, thank you very much and it is working correctly.

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please upvote my answer. :)