# Dynamic image in modal view with javascript in Laravel 5.2

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I need a little advice to display images dynamically.

I am currently using this script from an example of W3Schools:

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modal_images.asp

Here is the script:

```js
<script>
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

        // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
        var img = document.getElementById('myImg');
        var modalImg = document.getElementById("img");
        var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        img.onclick = function(){
            modal.style.display = "block";
            modalImg.src = this.src;
            captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
        }

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() { 
          modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
```

```html
@foreach($properties->files as $file) 
    
    <div class="col-md-6 thumb">
        <a class="thumbnail">
            <img id="myImg" src="{{ URL::asset('uploads/products/' . $file->name) }}" alt="{{ $file->name }}" width="300" height="200">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">

        <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>

        <img class="modal-content" id="img">
        
        <div id="caption"></div>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

I need to display the images that are displayed dynamically in the thumbnail, because only the first image in the list is showing.

In the view the images are shown like this:

[image]

The first image is displayed in a modal view, but the second does not:

[image]

This is my show method in Propertycontroller:

```
Public function show ($ id)
     {
         $ Properties = Property :: find ($ id);
        
         $ Files = File :: where ('property_id', $ properties-> id) -> get ();
        
         Return view ('properties.show', compact ('properties', 'files'));
     }
```

This requirement is related to:

[Show image file by id in Laravel 5.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41625187/show-image-file-by-id-in-laravel-5-2)

How can I display the images in the modal view when clicking them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's showing only first image because your `id` will be same for all images. Use `for` loop index to give unique id to `img` tag like below :

```
@foreach($properties->files as $index=>$file) 

<div class="col-md-6 thumb">
    <a class="thumbnail">
        <img id="myImg<?php echo $index ?>" src="{{ URL::asset('uploads/products/' . $file->name) }}" alt="{{ $file->name }}" width="300" height="200" onclick="showImage(this,<?php echo $index ?>)">
    </a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

`showImage()` function will pass the unique `$index` to your script and do the thing.

```
<script>
     function showImage(element,i){
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

    // Get the image and insert it inside the modal - use its "alt" text as a caption
    var img = document.getElementById('myImg'+i);
    var modalImg = document.getElementById("img");
    var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
        modal.style.display = "block";
        modalImg.src = element.src;
        captionText.innerHTML = element.alt;
   }
</script>
```

similarly you can set closing the modal logic. I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I applied your recommendations but returned the following error message: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: I have modified `showImage()`. try it now. And if you still get the same error cross check `$properties` value in your controller.

Comment: I applied the changes and did not display the images and displayed the same message.

Comment: Then there is some problem in your code ... can you post a screenshot of error.

Comment: Thanks for your help, last night I did not find the error, but I have already solved it, the problem was how I was placing the variable properties in the view.